# How to write switch case conditions for card type in angular6

Tags: angular

I am doing project in angular. I have written conditions for payment type, I need to write it in a switch case condition in angular6. Any help please!!
My code is here

```
myFunc(number){
 number=this.myModel.bank.value

 // visa
 var re = new RegExp("^4");
 if (number.match(re) != null){
  this.myModel.paymentType.value="Visa";
 }

 //Master Card

  var re=new RegExp("^5[1-5][0-9]{0,14}|^(222[1-9]|2[3-6]\\d{2}|27[0-1]\\d|2720)[0-9]{0,12}");
  if (number.match(re) != null){
    this.myModel.paymentType.value="Master Card";
  }

 // AMEX
 re = new RegExp("^3[47]");
 if (number.match(re) != null){
  this.myModel.paymentType.value="AMEX";
 }


 // Discover
 re = new RegExp("^(6011|622(12[6-9]|1[3-9][0-9]|[2-8][0-9]{2}|9[0-1][0-9]|92[0-5]|64[4-9])|65)");
 if (number.match(re) != null){
  this.myModel.paymentType.value="Discover";

 }

   //Switch card
    re = new RegExp("^(4903|4905|4911|4936|6333|6759)[0-9]{12}|(4903|4905|4911|4936|6333|6759)[0-9]{14}|(4903|4905|4911|4936|6333|6759)[0-9]{15}|564182[0-9]{10}|564182[0-9]{12}|564182[0-9]{13}|633110[0-9]{10}|633110[0-9]{12}|633110[0-9]{13}$");
    if (number.match(re) != null){
     this.myModel.paymentType.value="Switch Card";

    }

 return "";

    }
```

Comment: please follow the rules to post a question. Your question doesn't provide any info on what exactly you need help with? There are 1000's of online examples available regarding simple switch in ts file as well as in html file. Always do a research before asking and question and ask precisely on where you're facing the issues. Read this to understand more - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

**Switch case in angular**

It may help you

```
 yrFunction(check){

      switch (check){
        case 1:

          return this.tab = 'Dako_patel';

        case 2:

          return this.tab = 'Dako_patel__1';
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear if you want a simple switch case in your components.ts file or in the template file, in case you are referring the template:

```
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="true">
  <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="myModel.paymentType.value === 'Master Card'">

  </ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="myModel.paymentType.value === 'Visa'">

  </ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngSwitchDefault>

  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I want switch case in component.ts file

Comment: @user11759028 if that's not the answer you wanted, why have you marked this as accepted answer?